# Is there any research about mechanism design with more than two choice variables?

Tags: game-theory, auctions, mechanism-design

In traditional mechanism design problem, there are only two choice variables (regardless the payoff function of agent is quasilinear or not), which makes the strictly increasing difference of payoff function easy to check. For examples, if the agent's utility function is
$$u(x,p,\theta)=a(\theta)\cdot x-b(\theta)\cdot p$$
where $a(\cdot)$ and $b(\cdot)$ are strictly positive, and satisfy
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\frac{a(\theta)}{b(\theta)}>0.$$
Then it is very easy to prove that any incentive compatible outcome should be that $x(\theta)$ and $p(\theta)$ strictly increasing in $\theta$ by proving that $u(x,p,\theta)-u(x',p',\theta)$ is single crossing in $\theta$.

Now if another choice variable, $c$ gets involved, and the utility function becomes
$$u(x,p,c,\theta)=a(\theta)\cdot x-b(\theta)\cdot p-c,$$
the same result is no longer holds since the single crossing condition is not sufficient now. But it seems that we can still tell something about $x$ and $p$. Any research talking about this mechanism design problem with more than two choice variables?